# Issue with WooCommerce WC_Product set_category_ids() method in ACF "acf/save_post" hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have a problem assigning a product category to a Woocommerce product that I create with Php.
(Environment is Wordpress 5.6.1, Woocommerce 5.0, Php 7.4.14, ACF Pro 5.9.5, Oxygen 3.6.1)

All other attributes for the product gets saved while creating it, and I can see that the product object get updated with the category id prior to saving.

However, when saving - no product category gets assigned to the product. On the contrary - the product don´t even get the "Uncategorized" category. It gets none!

This is how I create the product.

```
$product = new WC_Product_Simple();

$product->set_status("publish");

$product->set_name($title);

$product->set_category_ids([$product_category]);

$product->set_stock_status('instock');

$product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');

$product->set_sold_individually(false);

$product->set_regular_price('300');

$product->set_description('Product description');

$product->set_image_id($logo_id);

$product_id=$product->save();
```

The code runs from my own plugin, and gets called from this action:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_create_product_from_form_submit', 20);
```

The idea is that a custom post type using an ACF form is used to fill the data for the product. After the custom post type post is published and data saved with ACF, my code triggers and creates a product from the data entered into the form.

Everything works fine - the custom post is created, as is the product. All attributes are saved to the product. The only problem is that the product never becomes assigned to a product category.

I have no errors in any log. It´s like the system completely ignores this line:

```
 $product->set_category_ids([$product_category]);
```

This is a dump of the product object, after the product->save() command is run. Note that on line 59, the category_ids are there.

Its, just like everything is set to work - but  the category id is not written to the db.

Any suggestions on how to solve this is highly appreciated.

```
   'object_type' => 'product',
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'cache_group' => 'products',
   'data' =>
  array (
    'name' => 'Name',
    'slug' => '',
    'date_created' =>
    WC_DateTime::__set_state(array(
       'utc_offset' => 0,
       'date' => '2021-02-16 23:58:03.000000',
       'timezone_type' => 3,
       'timezone' => 'Europe/Stockholm',
    )),
    'date_modified' => NULL,
    'status' => 'publish',
    'featured' => false,
    'catalog_visibility' => 'visible',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => '',
    'sku' => '',
    'price' => '300',
    'regular_price' => '300',
    'sale_price' => '',
    'date_on_sale_from' => NULL,
    'date_on_sale_to' => NULL,
    'total_sales' => '0',
    'tax_status' => 'taxable',
    'tax_class' => '',
    'manage_stock' => false,
    'stock_quantity' => NULL,
    'stock_status' => 'instock',
    'backorders' => 'no',
    'low_stock_amount' => '',
    'sold_individually' => false,
    'weight' => '',
    'length' => '',
    'width' => '',
    'height' => '',
    'upsell_ids' =>
    array (
    ),
    'cross_sell_ids' =>
    array (
    ),
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'reviews_allowed' => true,
    'purchase_note' => '',
    'attributes' =>
    array (
    ),
    'default_attributes' =>
    array (
    ),
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'post_password' => '',
    'virtual' => false,
    'downloadable' => false,
    'category_ids' =>
    array (
      0 => 33,
    ),
    'tag_ids' =>
    array (
    ),
    'shipping_class_id' => 0,
    'downloads' =>
    array (
    ),
    'image_id' => false,
    'gallery_image_ids' =>
    array (
    ),
    'download_limit' => -1,
    'download_expiry' => -1,
    'rating_counts' =>
    array (
    ),
    'average_rating' => 0,
    'review_count' => 0,
  ),
   'supports' =>
  array (
    0 => 'ajax_add_to_cart',
  ),
   'id' => 956,
   'changes' =>
  array (
  ),
   'object_read' => true,
   'extra_data' =>
  array (
  ),
   'default_data' => (ignoring the rest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mandatory:** The product category that you set on the product, need to be an **existing product category** term ID *(and doesn't work with WordPress category terms Ids)*.

I have tested your code and it works if variable `$product_category` is an integer,
so try to replace:

```
$product->set_category_ids([$product_category]);
```

with:

```
$product->set_category_ids( array_map('intval', [$product_category]) );
```

This should work.

**Documentation:** [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/array_map) and [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/intval) functions.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the reply!
I have replaced the code to set the category ids, but unfortunately, I have the same problem.

I have now deactivated all plugins except ACF Pro, Code Snippets, CPT UI, Woocommerce. 

Also, I have recreated the ACF form as a shortcode, to run it clean without Oxygen. 
But the problem still persists.

However - I have found out that I can create the custom post from the admin. Then my code to create the product runs, and then the category is created as expected.

So, I wonder if there is something that is related to ACF that causes this?

Comment: @NickLas Probably ACF `acf/save_post` hook disables something used by WooCommerce method `set_category_ids()`… I can't really confirm that. I will delete this answer soon.

Comment: yes, I think that is the case. I have reported this as a ticket to ACF. I will see what they reply. 
Again, thanks for a very detailed and good reply!

Comment: one note is that if you assign 1 category using set_category_ids() it'll remove it from all other categories already assigned.  So if you want to keep all the categories assigned to it, retrieve those array of ids and push the new id to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but... for thoose in doubt: you can create a category and use the ID (WC will give it a number - (integer)) when coding your plugin.

You can put your mouse over the category just created and a link with 'tag_ID' will show you your number. Hope that it can be usefull

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).